# what is relation of "int a=5" with scanf("%d",ptr) if [ "int* ptr"] ptr is pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

code

```
int *ptr;
int a=10;
scanf("%d",ptr);
printf("%d",*ptr);

output:-
5 //for scanf
5 //from printf
```

but

```
int *ptr;
// removing this `int a=10;`
scanf("%d",ptr);
printf("%d",*ptr);

output change :-
5 //for scanf
  //blank (nothing from printf)
```

and here I was trying to scanf value to pointer directly
so how can I scanf value to ptr

without

```
int a,*ptr;
ptr = &a;
```

is it compulsory to assign the address of another variable to ptr before putting(scanf) value in it

Comment: The both relate to undefined behaviour.

Comment: How would you try to scanf into an int? I ask because I suspect that you forgot that have to give a pointer to a variable, to scanf, not a variable. Where printf takes  `myvar`scanf needs `&myvar`. And that is why 273k above calls you out on undefined behaviour.

Comment: However, you also cannot read anything meaningful into a pointer, only into what a pointer points to.

Comment: In both cases `ptr` points nowhere, therefore the behavior of both code snippets is undefined. You probably simply want `scanf("%d", &a);`

Comment: I can understand if "ptr = &s" is compulsory but why "int a = 10 " affecting output even "int a" does not do the same

Comment: @HoneyHoney because it's **undefined behavior** (google that term)

Comment: It is a "nasal demon". Use your favorite search engine on that term. (Basically same as comment above, but more fun.)

Comment: thanks, I got undefined behavior  (ง •_•)ง

Comment: The pointer does not necessarily need to contain the address of another variable, but it must point to valid memory.  The address of another variable is one such possibility.  `scanf` is going to write data to the memory location referenced by the pointer.  If the pointer does not reference valid memory, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Also note that in C++ you can do `int a; std::cin >> a; std::cout << a;` without using any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "yes," it's necessary to assign a pointer to something before using it for pretty much anything (other than merely storing the pointer location). Point your pointer to the variable you use scanf() on. The code you titled "without" seems to be what you need.